# Objective C - NSRange and rangeOfString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, match, nsrange

I have a little problem with NSRange and rangeOfString. I want to search a substring in a given string which is working fine, but only to find a exact string and theres the problem i need to find a substring which begins always the same and ends always the same. I tried it already with something like that:

```
    match = [strIn rangeOfString: @"truni/begin/*/end"];
```

But thats not working. So i need a way to to do this. Here is the specific part of the Code in full:

```
    NSRange match;
    match = [strIn rangeOfString: @"turni/begin/sHjeUUej/end"];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(match.location, match.length);
    NSString *strOut = [strIN substringWithRange:range];
```

You see the string "turni/begin/sHjeUUej/end" will always be the same except for the part "sHjeUUej". Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at `NSRegularExpression`

Comment: `NSRegularExpression`, as per above mentioned, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression with:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask
```

with an option of `RegularExpressionSearch`.

See ICU User Guide [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) for information on creating regular expressions.

Comment: I'm new to Objective C could you please give me a bit more detail - that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

you can use prefix/suffix

```
if ([strIn hasPrefix:@"truni/begin/"] && [strIn hasSuffix:@"end"]) {
   //match
```

Comment: In this way i cannot use it the only way it would work is something like this:
    match = [inputsourcecode hasPrefix:@"truni/begin/"];

But this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler solution if you make sure that your string always starts with `turni/begin/` and ends with `/end`.

You can use:

```
NSString *strOut = [[strIn stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"turni/begin/" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/end" withString:@""];
```

With that, you can retrieve the string between the two others with only one line of code and less comparations.